# Laravel Redirection doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 5.1. My controller is specifically for admin users. So I check whether user is admin or not.This is my code.

```
public function getAdminData()
  {
    $this->checkAdminStatus();
    return response()->json(array('admin-data'));
  }
public function checkAdminStatus()
  {
    $userManager = new UserManager();
    if(!$userManager->isAdmin())
    {
        return redirect()->route('returnForbiddenAccess');
    }
  }
```

My route is

```
Route::any('api/app/forbidden',['uses' =>'ErrorController@returnNonAdminErrorStatus','as'=>'returnForbiddenAccess']);
```

Now if user is not admin, then it should not return `admin-data` yet it returns. Shouldn't it stop processing logic after `redirect()->route` call?
Also this is purely REST application.

Comment: Why would you check whether someone is an admin in your controller, if that controller is for admins only? Use middleware which will do the check for you, and if someone is authenticated and authorized - let them through to the controller. Otherwise send them to authorization page. This logic isn't done in controllers, it's done in middleware, just as per Jiedara's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use Laravel Middleware solution for your need ? You can link a middleware to your controller, checking if the current user is an administrator, and redirect if not :

```
//You Middleware Handle method
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if ($this->auth->guest() || !($this->auth->user()->isAdmin))
  {
        return redirect('your/url')->with('error','no admin');;
  }
return $next($request);
}
```

You can add on or multiple middleware for a controller in his construct method

```
//your controller
public function __construct(Guard $auth, Request $request){
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]); //here one 'auth' middleware
    $this->middleware('admin', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'create','store']]); //here the admin middleware
}
```

Notice the `only`and `except` parameters that allow or disallow the middleware for some controller methods

Check [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware) on Middleware for more information :)

Comment: Hmm that seems to be proper way to do it,can you tell me how add more than one middleware to controller?

Answer (score 1):

No, your logic is slightly flawed.  The return value you are sending back from `checkAdminStatus()` is simply being ignored and thrown away:

```
public function getAdminData()
{
    // You don't have $redirectValue in your code, but imagine it 
    // is there. To actually redirect, you need to return this value
    // from your controller method
    $redirectValue = $this->checkAdminStatus();
```

Nothing is being done with that redirect.  The *only* time something is being returned from your *controller* is happening on every single request.  I would suggest something more like this:

```
public function getAdminData(UserManager $userManager)
{
    if($userManager->isAdmin()) {
        return response()->json(array('admin-data'));
    }

    return redirect()->route('forbidden-access');
}
```

I think this captures the spirit of your question: the only time anything is being returned here is *if the user is an admin*.

---

As an aside, you are returning JSON data in one case, and a *redirect* in another.  This may not be a very good idea.  My reasoning is because, normally, JSON data is returned in response to AJAX requests, which in my experience are seldom followed up with an *actual* redirect in the event of failure.  <sup><sub>(YMMV)</sub></sup>

Comment: Actually previously I was doing that only. But then i would be rewriting this same code again in this whole controller, and I was trying to apply DRY principle. What if i inject middleware into it,since this is common for whole controller?

Comment: Yes if this code is going to be used over and over, it would make sense to put it inside of a middleware. I would negate the if statement in that case (`if(!$manager->isAdmin())`) and then only return the redirect in that case. In your controller then you just return the admin data JSON.

Comment: Hmm yes ,also can you tell me if i can add more than middleware to my controller , if yes then how?